# awk: setting environment variables directly from within an awk script

Tags: awk

first post here, but been a lurker for ages. i have googled for ages, but cant find what i want (many abigious topic subjects which dont request what the topic suggests it does ...). not new to awk or scripting, just a little rusty :)

i'm trying to write an awk script which will set shell env values as it runs - for another bash script to pick up and use later on. i cannot simply use stdout from awk to report this value i want setting (i.e. "export whatever=`awk cmd here`"), as thats already directed to a 'results file' which the awkscript is creating (plus i have more than one variable to export in the final code anyway).

As an example test script, to demo my issue:

```
echo $MYSCRIPT_RESULT          # returns nothing, not currently set
echo | awk -f scriptfile.awk   # do whatever, setting MYSCRIPT_RESULT as we go
echo $MYSCRIPT_RESULT          # desired: returns the env value set in scriptfile.awk
```

within scriptfile.awk, i have tried (without sucess)

1/) building and executing an adhoc string directly:

```
{
  cmdline="export MYSCRIPT_RESULT=1"
  cmdline
}
```

2/) using the system function:

```
{
  cmdline="export MYSCRIPT_RESULT=1"
  system(cmdline)
}
```

... but these do not work. I suspect that these 2 commands are creating a subshell within the shell awk is executing from, and doing what i ask (proven by touching files as a test), but once the "cmd"/system calls have completed, the subshell dies, unfortunatley taking whatever i have set with it - so my env setting changes dont stick from "the caller of awk"'s perspective.

so my question is, how do you actually set env variables within awk **directly**, so that a calling process can access these env values after awk execution has completed? is it actually possible?

other than the adhoc/system ways above, which i have proven fail for me, i cannot see how this could be done (other than writing these values to a 'random' file somewhere to be picked up and read by the calling script, which imo is a little dirty anyway), hence, help!

all ideas/suggestions/comments welcomed!

Comment: no can do. this is a basic rule of OS environments, child processes can change **their** environment but not the environment of their parent. The best you can do is, (from a shell script)  `myParentVar=$( echo "$myParentVar" | awk '{sub(/xxxx/, "yyyy", $0); print $0}' )`  (where `sub(...)` is a placeholder for whatever modifications you want to make to $myParetntVar. Good luck.

Comment: thx for the reply. i was affraid this was gonna be the case (parent/child env settings and scope of influence), so think i'm gonna have to go with a staging file for these env variables for the calling bash script to access.

thx for confirming what i thought anyway :(

Comment: I had a problem with this too. What I did was write the awk output to a temp file then sourced the temp file. Works. Not sure if it's elegant but still very unixy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot change the environment of your parent process. If

```
MYSCRIPT_RESULT=$(awk stuff)
```

is unacceptable, what you are asking cannot be done.

Comment: As answered above, you are right in that i'm attempting to adjust the parent env from the child, which is a no-no (didnt think of it this way when i first posted). this leaves 2 ways to move forwards: either make the return of awk (stdout) the result you are after, or if thats not possible (like myself) report these values into a text file, which the parent can then examine to get the values you are trying to pass back (in my case, use an env variable to tell awk where this "update file" is (using mktemp), making things a little cleaner in the code/implementation :)).

Comment: Belatedly also recommend switching the variable to lower case -- upper case is reserved for system variables, and should be avoided for your private variables.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use something like is described at 
[Set variable in current shell from awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505026/set-variable-in-current-shell-from-awk/33756188#33756188)

```
 unset var
 var=99
 declare $( echo "foobar" | awk '/foo/ {tmp="17"} END {print "var="tmp}' )
 echo "var=$var"
var=
```

The awk END clause is essential otherwise if there are no matches to the pattern declare dumps the current environment to stdout and doesn't change the content of your variable.

Multiple values can be set by separating them with spaces.

```
 declare a=1 b=2
 echo -e "a=$a\nb=$b"
```

NOTE: declare is bash only, for other shells, use eval with the same syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, but it's a bit of a kludge.  Since `awk` does not allow redirection to a file descriptor, you can use a fifo or a regular file:

```
$ mkfifo fifo
$ echo MYSCRIPT_RESULT=1 | awk '{ print > "fifo" }' &
$ IFS== read var value < fifo
$ eval export $var=$value
```

It's not really necessary to split the var and value; you could just as easily have awk print the "export" and just eval the output directly.

Comment: In `gawk` you can output to an alternate file descriptor that was opened in the parent shell. As an alternative, if `stderr` is not being otherwise used, it could be used as a way to output the value.

Comment: the fifo is an interesting idea, however there's a possibility (there always is) that the awk command could fail to return anything (error conditions), which then blocks execution at the fifo read (the awk script is not a one liner - far from it!). I like the idea of using stderr too, however stderr should be kept "clear of code" for those times if/when the script fails, as we dont want to introduce gibber into the program at runtime, therefore i dont think it's a good idea to use either - but thanks both anyway (i did say all ideas welcomed) - ive gone with tempfiles, it's just a little safer

Comment: up until today I had never heard of mkfifo. Thank you! mkfifo + nc = yes!

Answer (score 0):

I found a good answer. Encapsulate averything in a subshell!
The comand declare works as below:

```
#Creates 3 variables
declare var1=1 var2=2 var3=3
```

ex1:

```
#Exactly the same as above
$(awk 'BEGIN{var="declare "}{var=var"var1=1 var2=2 var3=3"}END{print var}')
```

I found some really interesting uses for this technique. In the next exemple I have several partitions with labels. I create variables using the labels as variable names and the device name as variable values.

ex2:

```
#Partition data
lsblk -o NAME,LABEL

NAME   LABEL
sda
├─sda1
├─sda2
├─sda5 System
├─sda6 Data
└─sda7 Arch

#Creates a subshell to execute the text
$(\
#Pipe lsblk to awk
lsblk -o NAME,LABEL | awk \
#Initiate the variable with the text for the declare command
'BEGIN{txt="declare "}'\
#Filters devices with labels Arch or Data
'/Data|Arch/'\
#Concatenate txt with itself plus text for the variables(name and value)
#substr eliminates the special caracters before the device name
'{txt=txt$2"="substr($1,3)" "}'\
#AWK prints the text and the subshell execute as a command
'END{print txt}'\
)
```

The end result of this is 2 variables: `Data` with value `sda6` and `Arch` with value `sda7`.

The same exemple in a single line.

```
$(lsblk -o NAME,LABEL | awk 'BEGIN{txt="declare "}/Data|Arch/{txt=txt$2"="substr($1,3)" "}END{print txt}')
```