# Set variable in current shell from awk

Tags: bash, variables, awk

Is there a way to set a variable in my current shell from within `awk`?

I'd like to do some processing on a file and print out some data; since I'll read the whole file through, I'd like to save the number of lines -- in this case, `FNR`.

Happens though I can't seem to find a way to set a shell variable with `FNR` value; if not this, I'd have to read the `FNR` from my output file, to set, say `num_lines`, with `FNR` value.

I've tried some combinations using `awk 'END{system(...)}'`, but could not manage it to work. Any way around this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
$ echo "$var"

$ declare $( awk 'BEGIN{print "var=17"}' )
$ echo "$var"
17
```

Here's why you should use declare instead of eval:

```
$ eval $( awk 'BEGIN{print "echo \"removing all of your files, ha ha ha....\""}' )
removing all of your files, ha ha ha....

$ declare $( awk 'BEGIN{print "echo \"removing all of your files\""}' )
bash: declare: `"removing': not a valid identifier
bash: declare: `files"': not a valid identifier
```

Note in the first case that eval executes whatever string awk prints, which could accidentally be a very bad thing!

Comment: +1 for the recommendation, but as long as it's me writing the code, I see no much of a problem using `eval`.

Comment: @Rubens, until the day when you accidentally do something bad. If you make it a habit to write safe code now, you won't get bitten in the future.

Comment: @glennjackman +1 thanks for the tip; I guess that's why safe coding is so considered here (:

Comment: I speak from experience... :(

Answer (score 41):

Here's another way.

This is especially useful when when you've got the **values** of your variables in a **single** variable and you want split them up. For example, you have a list of values from a single row in a database that you want to create variables out of.

```
val="hello|beautiful|world" # assume this string comes from a database query
read a b c <<< $( echo ${val} | awk -F"|" '{print $1" "$2" "$3}' )

echo $a #hello
echo $b #beautiful
echo $c #world
```

We need the 'here string' i.e <<< in this case, because the read command does not read from a pipe and instead reads from stdin

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! I have already a var with the strings separated by spaces, so I just gave that in input (like in "read a b c <<< $var). Thanks

Comment: one thing to mention, if the fields are separated with blankspace, this could simplified with:

```
read a b c <<< $(echo ${val})
```

Comment: Conversely, this does not work if there is whitespace inside one of your fields. You will end up with an incorrect division of output into your variables, with "runoff" read into the last variable, including spaces.

Comment: Actually there is no problem to read fields into variables when there are whitespaces inside. If the fields containing whitespaces are separated by another delim, you can set IFS (as well as awk delim) like that (here a comma is the delimeter): `IFS=',' read aa bb <<< $(echo ${line} | awk -F',' '{print $3","$4}')` If there are just whitespaces, you take only the required ones by their numbers.

Answer (score 7):

You can't export variables from a subshell to its parent shell. You have some other choices, though, including:

1. Make another pass of the file using AWK to count records, and use command substitution to capture the result. For example:

   ```
   FNR=$(awk 'END {print FNR}' filename)
   ```
2. Print *FNR* in the subshell, and parse the output in your other process.
3. If *FNR* is the same as number of lines, you can call `wc -l < filename` to get your count.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd options are what I'm trying to avoid, but I did not really get the idea from the first one. Isn't the first quite the same technique I'd use in the third one?

Comment: Yep, `FNR=$(awk 'END {print FNR}' filename)` and `FNR=$(wc -l filename | awk '{print $1}')` are quite the same, except by the one program counting the lines -- `awk`/`wc`.

Comment: you wouldn't really do that wc+awk combination, though, you'd just do `wc -l <filename` instead.

Answer (score 4):

A warning for anyone trying to use declare as suggested by several answers.

eval does not have this problem.

If the awk (or other expression) provided to declare results in an empty string then declare will dump the current environment.
This is almost certainly not what you would want.

eg: if your awk pattern doesn't exist in the input you will never print an output, therefore you will end up with unexpected behaviour.

An example of this....

```
 unset var
 var=99
 declare $( echo "foobar" | awk '/fail/ {print "var=17"}' )
 echo "var=$var"
var=99
The current environment as seen by declare is printed
and $var is not changed
```

A minor change to store the value to set in an awk variable and print it at the end solves this....

```
 unset var
 var=99
 declare $( echo "foobar" | awk '/fail/ {tmp="17"} END {print "var="tmp}' )
 echo "var=$var"
var=
This time $var is unset ie: set to the null string var=''
and there is no unwanted output.
```

To show this working with a matching pattern

```
 unset var
 var=99
 declare $( echo "foobar" | awk '/foo/ {tmp="17"} END {print "var="tmp}' )
 echo "var=$var"
var=
This time $var is unset ie: set to the null string var=''
and there is no unwanted output.
```

Comment: The problem is not so much the declare "default behaviour" as it is passing the $() without quotes. That will leave just empty space there, without declare every being the wiser about having a parameter. The proper solution would be, or at the very least *include*, quoting the declare parameter: ```declare "$( ... )"```

Answer (score 1):

Make `awk` print out the assignment statement:

```
MYVAR=NewValue
```

Then in your shell script, `eval` the output of your `awk` script:

```
eval $(awk ....)
# then use $MYVAR
```

EDIT: people recommend using `declare` instead of `eval`, to be slightly less error-prone if something other than the assignment is printed by the inner script. It's bash-only, but it's okay when the shell *is* bash and the script has `#!/bin/bash`, correctly stating this dependency.

The `eval $(...)` variant is widely used, with existing programs generating output suitable for `eval` but not for `declare` (`lesspipe` is an example); that's why it's important to understand it, and the bash-only variant is "too localized".

Comment: This is the only technically possible answer

Comment: @anishsane Seems reasonable to me (: Couldn't think of this, though. Thanks, Anton Kovalenko!

Comment: I would use `declare` instead of `eval`.

Comment: @anishsane et al - no, this is the wrong answer. Use `declare` instead of eval.

Comment: @chepner `declare` is bash-only, which is not necessarily bad, but that's why I'd not use it by default.

Comment: True, but I would strongly recommend using it over `eval` if it's available.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko - the OP is using bash. See the tags.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko isn't eval also a shell builtin? it is on my box, and I can't find any package on redhat that proivides */eval

Comment: @peteches eval *is* a shell builtin, it has to be (how would it assign variables otherwise?). The difference is that `eval` is portable to any bourne shell, while `declare` is specific to `bash`. Also, with `eval` you get an additional round of substitution (for variables, commands, that kind of thing), that's why people recommend `declare`.

Comment: @EdMorton: I meant only about "You can't export variables from a subshell to its parent shell"

Comment: The less insane solution is `var=$(awk 'END { print 17 }' </dev/null)`, with Awk providing only the value, and the shell deciding what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

To synthesize everything here so far I'll share what I find is useful to set a shell environment variable from a script that reads a one-line file using awk. Obviously a `/pattern/` could be used instead of `NR==1` to find the needed variable.

```
# export a variable from a script (such as in a .dotfile)
declare $( awk 'NR==1 {tmp=$1} END {print "SHELL_VAR=" tmp}' /path/to/file )
export SHELL_VAR
```

This will avoid a massive output of variables if a `declare` command is issued with no argument, as well as the security risks of a blind `eval`.

Answer (score -1):

echo "First arg: $1"
for ((i=0 ; i < $1 ; i++)); do
echo "inside"
echo "Welcome $i times."
cat man.xml | awk '{ x[NR] = $0 } END { for ( i=2 ; i<=NR ; i++ ) { if (x[i] ~ // ) {x[i+1]="      '$i'"}print x[i] }} ' > $i.xml
done
echo "compleated"

Comment: Can you format your code properly and add some explanation such that others can learn from it?