# Increment variable when matched awk from tail

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm monitoring from an actively written to file:

My current solution is:

```
ws_trans=0
sc_trans=0
tail -F /var/log/file.log | \
while read LINE
echo $LINE | grep -q -e "enterpriseID:"
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
((ws_trans++))
fi
echo $LINE | grep -q -e "sc_ID:"
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
((sc_trans++))
fi

printf "\r WSTRANS: $ws_trans \t\t SCTRANS: $sc_trans"

done
```

However when attempting to do this with AWK I don't get the output - the `$ws_trans` and `$sc_trans` remains `0`

```
ws_trans=0
sc_trans=0

tail -F /var/log/file.log | \
while read LINE
echo $LINE | awk '/enterpriseID:/ {++ws_trans} END {print | ws_trans}'
echo $LINE | awk '/sc_ID:/ {++sc_trans} END {print | sc_trans}'

printf "\r WSTRANS: $ws_trans \t\t SCTRANS: $sc_trans"

done
```

Attempting to do this to reduce load. I understand that AWK doesn't deal with bash variables, and it can get quite confusing, but the only reference I found is a non tail application of AWK.

How can I assign the AWK Variable to the bash `ws_trans` and `sc_trans`? Is there a better solution? (There are other search terms being monitored.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the variables using the option `-v`, for example:

```
$ var=0
$ printf %d\\n {1..10} | awk -v awk_var=${var} '{++awk_var} {print awk_var}'
```

To set the variable "back" you could use [declare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14505723/1135424), for example:

```
$ declare $(printf %d\\n {1..10} | awk -v awk_var=${var} '{++awk_var} END {print "var=" awk_var}')
$ echo $var
$ 10
```

Your script could be rewritten like this:

```
ws_trans=0
sc_trans=0

tail -F /var/log/system.log |
while read LINE
do
    declare $(echo $LINE | awk -v ws=${ws_trans} '/enterpriseID:/ {++ws} END {print "ws_trans="ws}')
    declare $(echo $LINE | awk -v sc=${sc_trans} '/sc_ID:/ {++sc} END {print "sc_trans="sc}')
    printf "\r WSTRANS: $ws_trans \t\t SCTRANS: $sc_trans"
done
```

Comment: How do I get it back out of AWK? - so as to get back the `awk_var` value back into `var`?

Comment: @itChi I updated the answer, give a try to `declare`

Comment: Brilliant, the variables now set, and update rather than hitting an individual value `declare $(echo $LINE | awk -v ws_trans=${ws_trans} '/enterpriseID:/ {++ws_trans} END {print "ws_trans=" ws_trans}')` ( I know I'm being a goon reusing the same name, will fix later) Follow up question, can I do two searches in one awk, and set two different variables?

Comment: @itChi Give a try to this, it does the two searches at once  `echo $LINE | awk -v ws=${ws_trans} -v sc=${sc_trans} '/enterpriseID:/ {++ws; print "ws_trans="ws; next} /sc_ID:/ {++sc; print "sc_trans="sc}'` notice the usage of `next`

Comment: Dude, you're a legend, I was wondering why it was printing out the rest of the file when I tried that. Single quotes around the whole thing and next. You are a god. Thank you so much for your help today.

Comment: @itChi more than welcome, nice that it worked out :-)